# How to implement shared element transition to onClickListener in RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, shared-element-transition

I'm currently following this [tutorial](https://medium.com/android-news/easy-android-shared-element-transition-ac36952a4a4#.slpz2rk68)   to implement a shared element transition between view (cards) in RecyclerView and activity but I'm not sure how can I do it since I'm using an onClickListener on MyRecyclerAdapter class to start a new activity. 
Just new in development, hope you can help me about it.

MyRecyclerAdapter.java

```
public class MyRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PaletteViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private List<Palette> palettes;

public MyRecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<Palette> palettes) {
    this.palettes = new ArrayList<Palette>();
    this.palettes.addAll(palettes);
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public PaletteViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.
            from(viewGroup.getContext()).
            inflate(R.layout.card_view, viewGroup, false);

    itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, ScrollingActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("P25", "Longanissa");
            context.startActivity(intent);


        }
    });
    return new PaletteViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(PaletteViewHolder paletteViewHolder, int i) {
    Palette palette = palettes.get(i);
    paletteViewHolder.titleText.setText(palette.getName());
    paletteViewHolder.contentText.setText(palette.getHexValue());
    paletteViewHolder.card.setCardBackgroundColor(palette.getIntValue());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return palettes.size();
}
```

animateIntent method:

```
public void animateIntent(View view) {

// Ordinary Intent for launching a new activity
Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourSecondActivity.class);

// Get the transition name from the string
String transitionName = getString(R.string.transition_string);

// Define the view that the animation will start from
View viewStart = findViewById(R.id.card_view);

ActivityOptionsCompat options =

ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this,
                viewStart,   // Starting view
                transitionName    // The String
        );
//Start the Intent
ActivityCompat.startActivity(this, intent, options.toBundle());
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the transition name of the view inside the onBindViewHolder. It needs to be different of the others viewHolder so get a way to make it different and unique (using palette.getName() if palette names are unique for example or use i).

Then you need to start the activity inside on click using the provided view:

```
ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(context, v, v.getTransitionName());
context.startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
```

I don't understand why you need animateIntent method. Hope it still helps